# Combining three R, G, B matrices into a single matrix of 3-tuples?

Tags: matrix, color, astronomy, fits-format

Working with *Mathematica 8* on *OSX* here.

I have three $1024 \times 1024$ matrices representing the counts from consecutive exposures onto a *CCD* with $R$, $G$, and $B$ filters on it, and am looking to combine the three matrices to get a nice color picture.

My first shot was something of the following sort:

```
ColorCombine[{
MatrixPlot[m13R - dark - bias, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#, 0, 0] &)],
MatrixPlot[m13G - dark - bias, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, #, 0] &)],
MatrixPlot[m13B - dark - bias, ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 0, #] &)]
}]
```

but it looks like `ColorCombine` messes with the resolution, and so what was originally $1024\times1024$ comes out looking rather pixelated.

What I'm thinking now is to do the equivalent of `Transpose` but am unsure as to how to combine my three matrices into a $1024\times1024$ matrix with a $3$-tuple at each entry. From there I think `Image[combined, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]` will work to plot the now-colored image.

For those interested, you can find the relevant data [here](http://bit.ly/1lDSPJ4).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can use `MapThread[List, {m13R, m13G, m13B}, 2]` (assuming these are `n` x `m` matrices) and then `ArrayPlot` on the output.

Comment: Why not `ColorCombine[Image/@({m13R, m13G, m13B}-dark-bias), "RGB"]`?

Comment: @gpap, using `MapThread[List, {m13R - k, m13G - k, m13B - k}, 2]`, where $k=dark + bias$, in conjunction with `Image[-2724/RGB, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]` provides a somewhat reasonable picture--at least one that can be adjusted to look good. ($-2724$ is a normalizing factor to scale matrix values into the range $0-1$.)

@kuba, @SimonWoods: Unfortunately both `Image[{m13R/65492, m13G/65530, m13B/65518}, Interleaving -> False]` and `ColorCombine[Image/@({m13R, m13G, m13B}-dark-bias), "RGB"]` produce black either black frames or a list of images, respectively.

Comment: If you are getting a black frame it suggests the arrays are scaled incorrectly. Try using `Rescale[{r, g, b}]` or using `ImageAdjust` on the final image.

Comment: @Kuba I just checked the filter used on "Copy of CCD Image 67.fit" and for me it shows up red, as expected. The filter comes up upon doing `Import[path, "Metadata"] // TableForm`

Comment: "Open" indicates that no filter was used.

Comment: [closely related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37823/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your data processed.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
FileNames["*.fit"]
```

> ```
> {"Copy of bias6.fit", "Copy of bias7.fit", "Copy of bias8.fit", "Copy of bias9.fit", 
> "Copy of CCD Image 64.fit", "Copy of CCD Image 65.fit", "Copy of CCD Image 66.fit",
> "Copy of CCD Image 67.fit", "Copy of dark12.fit"}
> ```

#### Upload the data:

```
pics = Import[#, "RawData"][[1]] & /@ Rest@FileNames["*CCD*.fit"]; (* 3 pics *)

bias = Import[#, "RawData"][[1]] & /@ FileNames["*bias*.fit"]; (*4 pics *)

dark = Import[FileNames["*dark*.fit"][[1]], "RawData"][[1]]; (* 1 pic *)
```

#### Data info:

```
{#, "EXPTIME", "FILTER"} /. Import[#, "Metadata"] & /@ FileNames["*.fit"] // Grid
```

> [image]

#### Processing

Exposure time is important, we have to rescale `dark` to the exposure time of observations. Here it means we have to divide by `60/20 == 3`.

Notice that `dark` has the `bias` so we have to subtract it before rescaling to not rescale `bias`. We can subtract `bias` from observations separately later.

```
reducedDark = (dark - Mean[bias]) /3. ;


reducedObs = (# - Mean@bias - reducedDark) & /@ pics;
{mean, std} = {Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#} &@ 
                             DeleteCases[ Clip[Flatten@reducedObs, {280, ∞}, {0, ∞}], 0]
```

> ```
> {331.636, 402.461}
> ```

And using, Simon's suggestion:

```
ImageAdjust[Image[Reverse@reducedObs, Interleaving -> False], 
            {0, 0, 1}, mean + {-.3 std, 1.5 std}, {0, 1}]
```

[image]

### Notes for readers:

Of course it's not even close to the observations reduction in astronomy. What we are missing here are e.g.:

- colors: filters in astronomy are not just `Red Green Blue`, here we are just doing an arbitrary composition. Take a look at [photometric systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system).
- we are not reducing with [`flat frames`](http://www.astro.uni-bonn.de/~mischa/datareduction/biasdarkflat.html)
- we should deconvolve [Point spread function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function)

etc. etc. I'm not pretending I know what they do :) I've just faced an idea of this on lab couple years ago. :)

p.s. [related Wolfram Blog topic](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/27/fixing-bad-astrophotography-using-mathematica-8-and-advanced-image-deconvolution/)

closely related: [How can I create a colour image using raw black and white data? (FITS data cube)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37823/5478)

Comment: Note that to get the colors correct also requires consideration of the relative sensitivity in each band. Incidentally, `RawData` can often be integer ADC counts, in which case arithmetic manipulation of the images might be painfully slow. This didn't occur in version 8 only because it had a bug whereby the data were returned as floating-point values even if the file only contained integers.

Comment: @OleksandrR. You mean CCD sensitivity right? Also filter profiles are not just *top hats* what readers should keep in mind.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Transpose` with its second argument:

```
(* example data *)
{r, g, b} = DiskMatrix[#, 100] & /@ {30, 20, 10};

Image[Transpose[{r, g, b}, {3, 1, 2}]]
```

[image]

But it is simpler to use the [`Interleaving`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interleaving.html) option of `Image`:

```
Image[{r, g, b}, Interleaving -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about the Interleaving Option yet. Good to know.