# stacking images

Tags: image-processing

I would like to take a series of night sky photographic images taken sequentially and enhance dim stars in a single image.  This is a standard function in astronomical image processing packages, but I believe it should be possible with a simple command or two in Mathematica. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47166/5478)

Comment: Unless we get more details about the images, and an explanation of what this has to do with **"stacking"** them, I would call this a duplicate of the question linked by @Kuba.

Comment: Kuba's link should help you with the stacking. As far as enhancing dim features, you can alter the gamma setting using `ImageAdjust[img, {0,0,0.25}]` to make dim objects brighter. Alternately, you can scale the imagedata by a constant factor greater than one.

Comment: This is interesting but please include sample input images and if possible the output that you desire.